# Horizontal Menu with vertical Sub menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want a horizontal Menu with Vertical Submenus that are taken from SQl Server Database , I need the vertical Sub Menu with Scroll bars, Can someone give me link for such menu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Stu Nicholls over at [CSSplay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/), he'll probably have something for you.

Comment: Any other website link please

Comment: I'm tempted to add a link to Google.com. Have you tried anything? Is there any code we can look at for you?

Comment: I just want a horizontal menu with vertical submenu that has scrollbar by adding values from database in a JSP Page

Comment: So you haven't tried anything? Because, if your select element has a specified height, with `overflow-y: scroll;` defined, and is then filled from your DB with more options than the height allows, then you will get your scrollbar automatically.

Comment: Ya the above image was working fine but user asked for change in style hence asking here

Comment: If it's just a style change, then the solution is probably just within your CSS rather than your markup. Apply a max-height and overflow as described to the div that holds the DB returns, and see if that gives you what you want. Without seeing some code, there really isn't much I can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I was needed same thing, so I can recommend to you following links:

[Create your own drop down menu with nested submenus using CSS and a little JavaScript](http://www.emanuelblagonic.com/2006/10/11/create-your-own-drop-down-menu-with-nested-submenus-using-css-and-a-little-javascript/)
[Mega Dropdown Menu Generator](http://www.menucool.com/drop-down-menu)
[Responsive horizontal navigation menu using pure CSS](http://jharaphula.com/responsive-horizontal-menu-pure-css/)

I hope you will find it usefull.